# jquery losing value of $(this) on ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, replace

Hi I am using jquery to make an ajax request to the database to add and remove favourites from the database. This works fine however I want to replace part of the href in the anchor link so that a user can add/remove again if required without refreshing the page e.g. the link is built as so http://article.local/favourite/delete/uniqueid therefore I need to replace the 'delete' with add and vise versa for the add favourite button. However I can't  use the class name otherwise this will apply to all of the classes rather than the one clicked at that time.

```
$( ".remove-favourite" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var favform = $(this).parent('.fav-form-contents');
    $(favform).append("<img src='/images/loading.gif' class='form-loader' class='loading-icon'/>");                    

 $.ajax({
         type     : "POST",
         cache    : false,
         url      : $(this).attr('href'),
         data     : $(this).serialize(),
        success  : function(data) {
             $('.loading-icon').hide();
            $(this).attr('href').replace(/delete/, 'add');
            $(this).removeClass('remove-favourite').addClass('add-favourite');
        }
      })
}); // end click function
```

However the error message I get back is as follows:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined`

This suggests that it has lost the current item, any ideas as to what I am doing wrong??

Comment: Please use the search function of SO. This is one of the most frequently asked questions here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to preserve `$(this)` in a variable for the callback like

```
var $link = $(this);
$.ajax({
         type     : "POST",
         cache    : false,
         url      : $(this).attr('href'),
         data     : $(this).serialize(),
        success  : function(data) {
             $('.loading-icon').hide();
            $link.attr('href').replace(/delete/, 'add');
            $link.removeClass('remove-favourite').addClass('add-favourite');
        }
  })
```

`this` itself will have changed because the execution context of the `success` callback in `$.ajax` is different then when you called `$.ajax`.

Comment: This isn't because "$.ajax is asynchoronous"...

Comment: @DenysSéguret, I said it is because the **success** callback **in** $.ajax is asynchoronous. Not $.ajax itself

Comment: Still totally wrong ^^

Comment: @DenysSéguret, can you please explain or point me to a link? I would really appreciate it

Comment: @DenysSéguret, surely the success callback is not synchronous?

Comment: `({fun:function(){ ['a'].forEach(function(){ console.log(this) })}}).fun()`. No asynchronicity here.  The asynchronicity isn't relevant to the problem. What is relevant is the context of the call of the callback.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, absolutely. I see now. Updating my answer.

Comment: Cool, I'll remove my downvote when it's done ;)

Comment: @DenysSéguret, ok, hows that?

Comment: ok. I took the liberty to add some semantics to the variable. Revert if you don't like that edit.

Comment: @DenysSéguret, no thats fine. Also, I notice you changed `$(this)` at the end to `this` which is more correct. Thanks for the helpful info, I have benefited! :)

Answer (score 1):

make **this** as global means with in function

like var `_this = $(this)` use in ajax suuceess

Comment: Not a good idea. Can have multiple `this` instances (of different things), and making it global will mess up everything.. @AmmarCSE's solution is best

Comment: i could not say like that  .assigning variable with in function

Comment: @AndreyPopov Read the code. "global" was just a poor choice of words, it's not global, just in the external scope.

Comment: Swearing is also a poor choice of words, but people suffer from them :) There is no such thing as "global within a function". This is called "member". Global means global, straightforward..

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside ajax is related to `xhr` object.

Use `context` option of ajax,

> This object will be the context of all Ajax-related callbacks. By default, the context is an object that represents the Ajax settings

```
$.ajax({
     context:this,
     ....
```